# JavaScript using regular expressions to look for words "19XX" or "18XX" in long string

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string

I am trying to go through a string to find dates in format of 19XX or 18XX, where XX can be any integers. Here is the basic set up:

```
var myLongString = "The Cold War (Russian: Холо́дная война́, Kholodnaya voĭna) was the continuing state from roughly 1946 to 1991 of political conflict...";

function getDates(myLongString) {
    //use regular expressions to create a list of words in the "19XX" or "18XX" format
    //and then return that list
```

}

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
return myLongString.match(/\b1[98]\d\d\b/g);
```

Comment: I would add word breaks to that otherwise you'll also match parts of numbers like 19222 and 91822